# How do I read a csv file from aws s3 in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to the AWS services.I am trying to read a csv file from AWS S3 bucket but I cannot read or get any output from AWS lambda.

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    try:
        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    
        csv_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)
        data = csv_file['Body'].read().splitlines(True)
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        print(reader)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

I am getting this output but I don't get data from my print line why is that? 
please help me!

[image: aws issue]

here is s3req test event
[image]

Comment: What is `s3req` test event?

Comment: Please don't post event as screenshot, but properly formatted json code block.

Comment: Can you print the contents of `data` to see whether it contains anything? Anything that is printed should appear in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

According to the documents, I think you used the wrong way of csv module. So the reader is empty and that's why your code does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to read csv is by using pandas.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=path)
content = pd.read_csv(response.get("Body"))
```

Comment: to add pandas for aws lambda need to add a layer, [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-python-pandas-layer-to-aws-lambda-bab5ea7ced4f) you can find how to add a layer